# Can I compile code on a VPS account?

Tags: windows-server-2008, compile, vps

I intend to purchase a Windows VPS account with the following: -

- Windows Server 2008 Standard 64-bit OS
- 2 GB RAM
- 1,000 GB/month bandwidth

I develop Windows software but not for so long, I just got started. I make exe's but I do not trust my home computer enough to make a final executable that can be shipped to customers, so I am thinking of doing the compilation elsewhere. Ideally I want to compile my code (make the dll's and the exe's) on a VPS account.

My code is in C++ and my GUI in Qt 4.7.

Will it be possible to compile my software on the VPS account (make exe's and dll's)?.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you have the software installed on the VPS to do the compiling.

Having a VPS is no different to having a real computer - just a little bit slower as you're sharing the hardware with others.

Comment: Unless your VPS is a "Virtual Pseudo Server", like Virtuozzo guests which can't install drivers lest they break the para-virtualisation. Or OpenVZ which has hard limits for process virtual memory (even unallocated virtual memory).

Comment: @taspeotis yuck - that sounds nasty.  I didn't get the impression that the OP was getting anything like that by his post.

Comment: I'm just ranting after blowing money on VPS' only to find out that "private server" meant "pseudo server". Your answer is completely correct, there's nothing fancy about code compilation that will trip up if the host is Virtuozzo or OpenVZ.